# How to make date time string to isoformat in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting a datetime string from `pyqt5`

```
edt = self.home_ui.end_date_time.dateTime()
print(type(edt))
edt_string = edt.toString(self.home_ui.start_date_time.displayFormat())
print(edt_string)
```

which looks like below:

```
<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime'>

2020-09-21 11:32:00
```

I want to convert it to below format:

```
2020-09-21T11:32:00
```

I tried:

```
edt_string = datetime.datetime.strptime(edt_string, "yyyy-M-dTh:mm:ss")
```

Can anyone please help me here. Thanks

Comment: if you have a python datetime, you can just use `datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()`

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tried doing this on `edt_string` but its not working

Comment: try `edt.isoformat()` - it's a method of the datetime object, not string.

Comment: @MrFuppes Tried that too, `isoformat` for `edt` is not available

Comment: ok so what dtype is `edt`? does it have a method to convert to datetime object first?

Comment: @MrFuppes Its `<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime'>`. Applogies, I forgot to add this in question.

Comment: @MrFuppes `AttributeError: 'QDateTime' object has no attribute 'isoformat'`

Comment: `edt.toPyDateTime().isoformat()` could work

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes it is working fine. I you can answer, I will accept.

Comment: @SAndrew: I'm glad if it helped, just give [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22451283/10197418) a +1 ;-)