# How to read back entries from sqlite with date from qt qdateedit widget

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I have saved date entries in a sqlite database table. The date fields were converted to a format taken from qdatewidget like this:

```
due_date = self.dateEdit.date().toString(self.dateEdit_3.displayFormat())
```

which makes it a string like 10/14/2021, but saves it as a date, which is fine.

Now i would like to read this entries back, but sqlite wont give anything back when i try this:

```
day = (self.dateEdit_2.date().toString(self.dateEdit_3.displayFormat()))
```

because day then is also a string 10/14/2021, but the entries in sqlite are date. How could i solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "saves it as a date"? There isn't a specific datatype for dates in sqlite. You seem to be making some kind of distinction between "string" and "date", but it's not at all clear what you mean by that.

Comment: I have set the type of the database table field to date, so the data is stored as date type.

Comment: In sqlite, DATE and DATETIME are the same as NUMERIC. There is no specific date type. If you set a value like `10/14/2021`, sqlite will store it as TEXT, because it can't be interpreted as an INTEGER or REAL. In sqlite, you need to use the [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to handle such values correctly.

Comment: If you're using the python sqlite3 module, you can [configure it to read/write python datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1829872/984421). Also, pyqt has [convenience methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22451283/984421) for converting `QDate/QDateTime` objects to python datetime objects.

Comment: if this would be true I wouldn't have a problem because I try to read the values with a string type. like where date ="14/10/2021". it fails because the table field is a date type

Comment: But that's simply because `"14/10/2021" != "10/14/2021"`.

Comment: as you can see in the second peace of coding I take the date from a qdate object, namely a qdateedit. I only get a string type value out of it, that is the problem cause sqlite has a date type field

Comment: in sqlite it is 14/10/2021 and I am reading with 14/10/2021. it fails because of the different types

Comment: From the docs: [SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype). So you can only store dates as TEXT, INTEGER or REAL.

Comment: ok let's say it stores a text. how would you ever find out a date greater than 14/10 /2021?

Comment: You would need to store the dates in a *sortable* format - i.e. as numeric values (timestamps), or `YYYY-MM-DD` if using strings. If you use a format like `DD/MM/YYYY`, "14/10/2021" would evaluate greater than "01/11/2021", because the comparison is done character by character, left to right.

Comment: now we are running in circles. a string is what I already have and it doesn't work.

Comment: meahnwhile i found out that this select statement         data = helper.select(f"select date(DateEdit) from DateEdit where DateEdit >= (select date('now'))") 
is getting entries entries from today on. Here one can see that the select date('now') is a date type field and the entries in sqlite are also stored as datetype date.

Comment: Let's see: `SELECT date('now')` -> `2021-10-15`; `SELECT typeof(date('now'))` -> `text`. So it's just a *string value*, exactly as the SQLite docs say. Now let's try: `SELECT date("14/10/2021")` -> `NULL`. This happens because the `date()` function requires strings in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. So: `SELECT date("2021-10-14")` -> `2021-10-14`; and of course, `SELECT typeof(date("2021-10-14"))` -> `text`. So, in all cases, you're just comparing *strings*, and they have to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` to get meaningful results.

Comment: then i am in a illusion beliving that due_date = self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate() converts it to a date. In the debugger i can see a date format for due_date after that. Secondly, if i open the table with sqlitestudio and look at the field types i see Date, Datetime, Time, etc.

Comment: As I already explained in my third comment above, PyQt provides convenience methods for converting `QDate/QDateTime` objects to [python datetime objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). So no mystery there. And as I also explained in my second comment, in SQLite, `DATE` and `DATETIME` are just [typename aliases](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples) for `NUMERIC` - so again, no mystery.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to compare string values with different formats, i.e. `"14/10/2021" != "2021-10-14"`. The SQLite date and time functions *cannot parse arbitrary date formats*. You MUST use one of the [supported formats](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values). The solution to your problem is to convert all the dates in your db to the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Then if you want to display the values in a different format, you can do e.g. `SELECT strftime('%d/%m/%Y', '2012-10-14')` -> `14/10/2021`.

Comment: I is a string yes. I found out when i save the entries like 
        date_to_save = self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate()
and read them back like 
        date_to_read_from = "'" + str(self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate()) + "'"
        date_to_read_to = "'" + str(self.dateEdit_2.date().toPyDate()) + "'"
        data = helper.select(f"select date(DateEdit) from DateEdit where DateEdit between 
      {date_to_read_from} and {date_to_read_to}")
it works. The dates must be in ' quotes.

Comment: It's completely unnecessary to manually add quotes, and [generally bad practice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders) to construct select statements using string operations. You should always try to use parameter substitution. What is `helper.select()`? If it's a third-party sqlite package, it should automatically handle the substitutions for you. If it doesn't, it's not secure, and you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Also note that `str(self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate())` will return a string like this: `2021-10-17`. Have you made sure that all the values in your `DateEdit` column are in that exact same format? Because if they're not, your select statements cannot produce reliable results.

Comment: helper.select is just a def i am using:     def select(self, query):  Select *       c = self.cursor        c.execute(query)        return c.fetchall(). I changed the variable to :         date_to_read_from = self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate()
and the selection to DateEdit between '{date_to_read_from}'.  the toPyDate() is always saving in format 2021-10-17 no matter what system language i choose. I tryed with us and german. both works fine.

Comment: Change it to: `def select(self, query, *params): return self.cursor.execute(query, params).fetchall()`. And note that the sqlite3 module knows how to convert python datetime objects. So using the above function, your query reduces to: `data = helper.select('SELECT DateEdit FROM DateEdit WHERE DateEdit BETWEEN ? AND ?', self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate(), self.dateEdit_2.date().toPyDate())`. (NB: there's no point in doing `date(DateEdit)`, since that just passes the value through unchanged).

Comment: ok thanks alot, i learned so much.